# Int value stored as empty string in database, trying to set new value to old value creates a "cannot convert string to int" problem

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I have a form which allows users to not input a value for customer_no which is an int value. It is stored in the database as an empty string I presume?

Here is the column   `customer_no INT(11) NULL,`

Why is it stored like this? I am trying to create a trigger for when the value is null or '' to use the old value stored. Yet it has the error of cannot convert string to int. Any help? Here is the trigger body

```
 IF NEW.customer_no IS NULL OR NEW.customer_no= '' 
 THEN SET NEW.customer_no= OLD.customer_no;
 END IF;
```

> [Field error in object 'form' on field 'customer_no ': rejected value []; codes 
>      [typeMismatch.form.customer_no ,typeMismatch.customer_no ,typeMismatch.int,typeMismatch]; arguments 
>      [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes 
>      [form.customer_no ,customer_no ]; arguments []; default message [customer_no ]]; default message [Failed to 
>      convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for 
>      property 'customer_no '; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input 
>      string: ""]]
>   `

I am using springboot and a jdbc query to get the information from from the form and update the database however when the value is null (rather than an integer value) It shows this error. I want the user to have the option to not enter a value for this field, if they want to update other fields, and still keep the old value previously entered for this particular one.

For example if the previously entered customer_no was 5 in the database and a user updates another column in the database and not enter a value for this field the trigger should use the old value stored of 5 instead of null yet it says "cannot convert string to int"

Hope that made a bit of sense

Thank you

Comment: Not entirely sure what's going on here. The error message isn't coming from your DB.  It looks like whatever serverside code you have isn't receiving input for that field

Comment: Hope my edit helps a bit @WillardSolutions, I can post my update query however I believe its not the query as its just getting the values from the form. Its when it submits a null value (or empty value) into the database, I think it stores it as a string rather than an int or NULL value (even though the data type is INT. I think it wants me to convert the string to an int then the int value to the old value I want stored in the database.

Comment: Thanks @pcoates that fixed it :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the field in the class receiving the form from int to Integer. It should then get a null value, which I think is what you're after.